# How to find out which localization is currently in use?

Tags: ios, localization

my app supports four different languages and I need to tell my server which one is used, so that the data from the server will be in the correct language. Which of the many language/locale classes will provide me with the information which of MY translations is currently in use.

So if the device is Russian (which I do NOT have a translation for) it will default back to English (I guess), so I need to know that "en" is currently in use. If the device is Italian (which I DO have a translation for) I obviously need to know that it is "it".

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some additional testing and research I could answer it myself and I found out that the following will provide the correct answer.

```
NSString* language = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] preferredLocalizations] firstObject];
```

The `[[NSBundle mainBundle] preferredLocalizations]` will provide you an ordered list of languages which are also supported by your app. It will only give you the language part though. So just "en" and not "en-US".

I have not tested this across multiple versions of iOS, but it works in iOS 10.

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 3 you can use

```
let localization = Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations.first
```